# An error ouucrred while I calling the write function of the QTcpSocket class from a QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I am learning about Multi-threaded programming in Qt, and then while I'm calling the write function of the `QTcpSocket` class from a `QThread`.The function output is:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QNativeSocketEngine(0x6f1840), parent's thread is QThread(0x624e90), current thread is QThread(0x716ed0)
```

The code that I called the write function:

```
QString Processor::GetSystemInfoOfClient() const
{
    QString result;
    const char *send_buffer = "GSIOC";
    char receive_buffer[100];
    this->cli_sock->write(send_buffer);
    this->cli_sock->waitForBytesWritten();
    this->cli_sock->waitForReadyRead(100000);
    this->cli_sock->read(receive_buffer, 100);
    result = QString(receive_buffer);
    return result;
}
```

The code that I accept the connections:

```
void Processor::Accept()
{
    this->cli_sock = m_server->nextPendingConnection();
    this->cli_addr = this->cli_sock->peerAddress();
    this->cli_port = this->cli_sock->peerPort();
}
```

The definition of the connection processor:

```
class Processor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Processor(QObject *parent = 0, QTcpServer *server = nullptr);
private:
    QTcpServer *m_server = nullptr;
    QTcpSocket *cli_sock = nullptr;
    QHostAddress cli_addr;
    quint16 cli_port;

    QString GetSystemInfoOfClient() const;
signals:
   void GetDetailedFinished(const QString &address,const QString &port, const QString &SystemInfo);
public slots:
   void GetClientDetail();
   void Accept();
};
```

Then I move the processor to the `QThread`

```
    Processor *processor = new Processor(0, server);
    processor->moveToThread(&processor_thread);
    connect(&processor_thread, &QThread::finished, processor, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(this, &Processor_Controller::Accept, processor, &Processor::Accept);
    connect(this, &Processor_Controller::GetClientDetail, processor, &Processor::GetClientDetail);
    connect(processor, &Processor::GetDetailedFinished, this, &Processor_Controller::PassClientDetail);
    processor_thread.start();
```

And I create the `QTcpServer` in the main thread.

```
    // The address of the server
    QHostAddress srv_addr("127.0.0.1");

    // The server listen port
    quint16 srv_port = 9895;

    Processor_Controller *controller = new Processor_Controller(0, &server);

    connect(&server, &QTcpServer::newConnection, controller, &Processor_Controller::BeginProcess);

    connect(controller, &Processor_Controller::DisplayClientDetail, this, &MainWindow::DisplayClientDetail);

    // BeginListen
    if(!server.listen(srv_addr, srv_port))
        emit statusBar()->showMessage("Listen Failed");
    else
        emit statusBar()->showMessage("Listen Success");
```

The function that call to the `GetSystemInfoOfClient` function:

```
void Processor::GetClientDetail()
{
    QString address    = this->cli_addr.toString();
    QString port       = QString::number(this->cli_port);
    QString SystemInfo = this->GetSystemInfoOfClient();
    emit this->GetDetailedFinished(address, port, SystemInfo);
}
```

The constructor of the Processor:

```
Processor::Processor(QObject *parent, QTcpServer *server) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->m_server = server;
}
```

I just want to create a server in main thread and process the connections in the Processor class. How I can avoid this error without changing this thinking?

Comment: when you initialize `cli_sock` variable try to set enclosing `Processor` object as it's parent

Comment: I hava tried to do that but it didn't make much difference

Comment: more ideas to play around: 1) Create `cli_addr` on the heap, not on the stack 2) Show us code for `Processor` constructor. This error is about thread affinity, i.e. you create some `QObject` in one thread and using in another

Comment: where is the call to `GetSystemInfoOfClient`?

Comment: The Processor constructor has only a line  code:
    Processor::Processor(QObject *parent, QTcpServer *server) :  QObject(parent)
    {
        this->m_server = server;
    }

Comment: Still, where's your `cli_sock` initialization code? You shouldn't set parent via `QObject::SetParent` but use `QTcpSocket` constructor instead.

Comment: @Alexey Andronov 
I try to do that but it also cannot solve any problem

Comment: @Alexey Andronov I try to initialization `cli_sock` but its error output is also like that after I use `QObject::SetParent` it outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem just using these two line of codes in `Processor::Accept` function

```
QTcpSocket *m_socket = m_server->nextPendingConnection();
this->cli_sock->setSocketDescriptor(m_socket->socketDescriptor(), m_socket->state(), m_socket->openMode());
```

Comment: please take a look at [Qt Threaded Fortune Server Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html) and the way they implement a multi-threaded server and follow their pattern.

Comment: see the note at the end of `setSocketDescriptor`'s [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketDescriptor), *It is not possible to initialize two abstract sockets with the same native socket descriptor.*. In your code you are using the same socket descriptor in `cli_sock` and `m_socket`. you will have problems soon or later. . .

Comment: I will see the Example, and the `m_socket` just like a Temporary object , I will use it for nothing.